# Add L2 regularization to specific embeddings in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am building a model like wide & deep using Tensorflow. For discrete features I first embed them into vector space and I am wondering how to add L2 normalization on embeddings.

The L2 regularization operator `tf.nn.l2_loss` accept the embedding tensor as input, but I only want to regularize `specific embeddings whose id appear in current batch of data`, not the whole matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `specific embeddings whose id appear in current batch of data` to calculate regularization loss.

```
import tensorflow as tf

ids = sparse_tensor.values
uniq_ids, _ = tf.python.ops.array_ops.unique(ids)    
embedding_index_slices = tf.gather(large_embedding_variable, uniq_ids) 
regularization_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(embedding_index_slices.values)

...

loss = train_loss + FLAGS.l2 * regularization_loss
```